# Pushing data into Array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I am trying to make push information to an array, but for some reason something isn't going well. When I try to get the length of my array `businessList`, it will result in 0, while there are supposed to be 3. This is what the array looks like in the console:

[image]

I know this is not what an array should look like in the console. It seems like the push is not working in my snapshot function. I am using this code:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var businessesRef = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userId + "/businesses");

businessesRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {

  var businessList = [];

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var getListOfBusinesses = firebase.database().ref('/businesses/' + key + "/info");

    getListOfBusinesses.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var name = snapshot.val().name;
      var contact = snapshot.val().contact;
      var pic = snapshot.val().pic;

      $( "#businesses" ).append( '\
        <div class="business">\
          <div class="business-img"><img class="profilepic-m" src="' + pic + '" /></div>\
          <div class="business-arrow"></div>\
          <div class="business-text">\
            ' + name + '<br/>\
            <span class="sidebar-sub">' + contact + '</span>\
          </div>\
        </div>'
      );
      businessList.push(name); 
    });
  });
  console.log(businessList);   
});
```

Comment: I guess that the businessList variable you defined at the top of the first .then callback is not in scope when you try to use .push.  As a test you could move the definition to global scope and see if that works.

Comment: i wouldn't use 'name' as a variable... http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: Im not sure I see an issue. Console is telling you that you have an array '[ ]' with 3 items - in position 0,1 and 2 and that the prototype object is 'Array'. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @Korgrue good point :)

Comment: @James I think that's the case. When I right-click in the console and select 'Store as Global variable', it gives me the correct array in the console. But I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: @Korgrue the problem is that I can not work with it right now. If I try to get the length or use `forEach` on it, nothing happens :(

Comment: Add this to your script, after where the array is populated and see if it prints out the first item in console.

console.log(businessList[0]);

Comment: Well, to make it a global variable move the `var businessList...` definition outside of the function it's it (above `businessesRef.once...`, probably)

Comment: @Korgrue it is undefined. However, if I log the array in the console right after the push command, it will give 3 correct arrays. So I will see 3 arrays with 1, 2 and 3 items. I am doing something wrong with the scope ..

Comment: @James That did not make any difference :(

Comment: Well, if the code you posted here is wrapped inside another function you'd have to move it outside of that too, to global scope (qv).

Comment: @James I did put it right after the `<script>` tag and logged the array right before the `</script>` tag, but it doesn't make any difference. I think something is wrong with the .push

Comment: I noticed that the push isn't working in .foreach, but it is working when I put it in the first .then. I really need it to work in the .foreach

Comment: I solved it in a different way. I will now run a function when the array.length is the same as the number of results from the database. Initially, I planned to put that function in another place, but this will work too. Thanks anyways!